# Dragging multiple elements at the same time in FullCalendar using React+Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, drag-and-drop, fullcalendar

I'm encountering an issue with my React application using FullCalendar and Draggable from FullCalendar Interaction. When I try to drag one of the blocks from the "Bölgeler" div into the calendar, it drops more than one event at the drop location. Also, it doesn't seem to add anything to the events list.

Here's my current code:

```
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react";
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
import interactionPlugin, {
  Draggable,
  DropArg,
} from "@fullcalendar/interaction";
import allLocales from "@fullcalendar/core/locales-all";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

interface MyEvent {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  date: string;
  color: string;
}

function App() {
  const [events, setEvents] = useState<MyEvent[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const containerEl = document.querySelector("#bolgeler");

    if (containerEl instanceof HTMLElement) {
      new Draggable(containerEl, {
        itemSelector: ".bolge",
        eventData: (eventEl) => {
          return {
            id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000).toString(),
            title: eventEl.innerText,
            color: window.getComputedStyle(eventEl).backgroundColor,
          };
        },
      });
      console.log(events);
    } else {
      console.error("Container element not found");
    }
  }, []);

  const handleEventDrop = (dropInfo: DropArg) => {
    const { draggedEl, date } = dropInfo;
    const title = draggedEl.innerText;
    const color = window.getComputedStyle(draggedEl).backgroundColor;

    const newEvent = {
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000).toString(),
      title,
      date: date.toISOString(),
      color,
    };

    setEvents((prevEvents) => [...prevEvents, newEvent]);

    console.log(events);
  };

  const handleEventRemove = (eventToRemoveId: string) => {
    setEvents((prevEvents) =>
      prevEvents.filter((event) => event.id !== eventToRemoveId)
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div id="takvim">
        <FullCalendar
          windowResizeDelay={100}
          handleWindowResize={true}
          height={650}
          plugins={[timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
          slotLabelFormat={{
            hour: "2-digit",
            minute: "2-digit",
          }}
          editable={true}
          droppable={true}
          allDaySlot={false}
          dayHeaderFormat={{
            weekday: "long",
          }}
          locales={allLocales}
          locale={"tr"}
          buttonText={{
            today: "Bugün",
          }}
          events={{ events }}
          drop={() => handleEventDrop}
          eventClick={(info) => {
            if (
              window.confirm(
                `Are you sure you want to delete the event '${info.event.id}'?`
              )
            ) {
              handleEventRemove(info.event.id);
            }
          }}
        />
      </div>

      <div id="bolgeler">
        <p>
          <strong>Bölgeler</strong>
        </p>
        <div className="bolge" style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}>
          Bölge 1
        </div>
        <div className="bolge" style={{ backgroundColor: "green" }}>
          Bölge 2
        </div>
        <div className="bolge" style={{ backgroundColor: "blue" }}>
          Bölge 3
        </div>
        <div className="bolge" style={{ backgroundColor: "orange" }}>
          Bölge 4
        </div>
        <div className="bolge" style={{ backgroundColor: "brown" }}>
          Bölge 5
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

I'm using useState to maintain the events list and useEffect to initialize the Draggable feature for the blocks from the "Bölgeler" div. The handleEventDrop function is triggered on drop, where I create a new event and try to update the events list using setEvents, but it doesn't reflect the expected behavior.

I expect that when I drag a block onto the calendar, it should only drop one event and add that event to the events list. However, it seems to drop multiple events and doesn't update the list correctly.

How can I ensure that only one event is dropped when dragging a block onto the calendar, and how can I fix the issue with updating the events list accordingly?

[image: When I drag one of the "Bölgeler" blocks into the calendar it should only drop one]

Answer (score 0):

Since you've provided `eventData` for the Draggable, fullCalendar will automatically create an event in the calendar for you when you drag and drop it onto your calendar. See [External Event Dragging](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/external-dragging) from the fullCalendar documentation for more details (in the "Associating Event Data" section).

You shouldn't need to also call `setEvents()` - so in fact you probably don't need to handle the `drop` callback at all. I'm not a React user, but I strongly suspect that's what is causing your dropped event to appear twice.